# Shortcut to automatically add custom editor for Script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

The Unity context menu for Assets has all kinds of useful shortcuts, but there is no shortcut to quickly create a custom editor. Instead, if I want to create a custom editor, I have to go through all these annoying boilerplate steps:

1. Create `Editor` directory (if not created yet), and go to the right sub-directory
2. `Create` -> `C# Script` (which should actually be called `C# Component Script`)
3. Remove all the `MonoBehavior` stuff
4. Append `Editor` to the class name
5. Add `using UnityEditor`
6. Add the `CustomEditor` attribute
7. Inherit from `Editor`

...before being able to actually start writing my stuff...

Is there a shortcut for that somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## New "Add Custom Editor" MenuItem

I wrote [this little script](https://gist.github.com/Domiii/7df09313f3aae3d32fccae1434ea6e9c) which adds a new `Add Custom Editor` [MenuItem](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html) to the `Assets` context menu:

[image: new MenuItem]

### Usage

1. Right-click a `Component` script in the `Scripts` folder.
2. Select `Add Custom Editor`.
3. The component now has an `Editor` which gets automatically selected, so you can modify it as you like. It has the same name (with `Editor` appended) and is at the same relative path, but in the `Scripts/Editor` folder

The screenshots below show an example: Given script `Scripts/Test/TestScript`, it creates a new editor at `Scripts/Editor/Test/TestScriptEditor`.

**NOTE**: The MenuItem will be disabled unless you have selected a Script that:

1. Has a `.cs` file ending
2. Is located somewhere under the `Scripts` folder (can be nested in any sub-directory)
3. Is not in the `Editor` folder
4. Does not have an editor yet

[image: after using it]

## Setup

1. `Create` -> `C# Script`
2. Call it `AddCustomEditorMenuItem`
3. Replace its contents with the code from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Domiii/7df09313f3aae3d32fccae1434ea6e9c)
4. Done!
5. Test it: Right-click a script file in the `Scripts` directory.

## Code Highlights

- Figuring out all the paths took most of the time:

```cs
scriptName = scriptAsset.name;

// get system file path
scriptPath = Path.GetFullPath(ProjectRoot + AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath (scriptAsset));

// get file name of the editor file
editorFileName = GetEditorFileNameFor (scriptName);

// split the script path
var results = scriptPathRegex.Matches (scriptPath).GetEnumerator ();
results.MoveNext ();
var match = (Match)results.Current;
scriptsPath = match.Groups [1].Value;
scriptRelativePath = match.Groups [2].Value;

// re-combine editor path
editorPath = Path.Combine (scriptsPath, "Editor");
editorPath = Path.Combine (editorPath, scriptRelativePath);
editorPath = Path.Combine (editorPath, editorFileName);

// nicely formatted file path
editorPath = Path.GetFullPath(editorPath);
editorRelativeAssetPath = editorPath.Substring(ProjectRoot.Length);
```

- Once, paths are figured out, actually writing the file is nice and easy!

```cs
public void WriteCustomEditorFile ()
{
  // create all missing directories in the hierarchy
  Directory.CreateDirectory (Path.GetDirectoryName (editorPath));

  // write file
  File.WriteAllText (editorPath, BuildCustomEditorCode(scriptName));

  // let Asset DB pick up the new file
  AssetDatabase.Refresh();

  // highlight in GUI
  var os = AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath(editorRelativeAssetPath);
  EditorGUIUtility.PingObject (os[0]);

  // log
  Debug.Log("Created new custom Editor at: " + editorRelativeAssetPath);
}

// ...

/// <summary>
/// The menu item entry
/// </summary>
[MenuItem ("Assets/Add Custom Editor %#e", false, 0)]
public static void AddCustomEditor ()
{
  var scriptAsset = Selection.activeObject;

  // figure out paths
  var scriptPathInfo = new ScriptPathInfo (scriptAsset);

  // write file
  scriptPathInfo.WriteCustomEditorFile ();
}
```

- If you don't like the default contents of a newly created editor, feel free to edit this part:

```cs
static string BuildCustomEditorCode (string name)
{
  return @"using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
[CustomEditor(typeof(" + name + @"))]
public class " + name + @"Editor : Editor {

public override void OnInspectorGUI ()
{
  base.OnInspectorGUI ();
  var obj = (" + name + @") target;
  if (GUILayout.Button (""Hi!"")) {
    // do something with obj when button is clicked
    Debug.Log(""Button pressed for: "" + obj.name);
    EditorGUIUtility.PingObject (obj);
  }
}
}";
}
```

- If your menu item is always grayed out, consider first checking out my explanations above, before debugging the code that determines if a valid script is selected:

```cs
[MenuItem ("Assets/Add Custom Editor %#e", true, 0)]
public static bool ValidateAddCustomEditor ()
{
  var scriptAsset = Selection.activeObject;

  if (scriptAsset == null) {
    // nothing selected? (should probably not happen)
    return false;
  }

  var path = ProjectRoot + AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath (scriptAsset);

  if (!scriptPathRegex.IsMatch (path)) {
    // not a Script in the Script folder
    return false;
  }

  if (editorScriptPathRegex.IsMatch (path)) {
    // we are not interested in Editor scripts
    return false;
  }
    

  if (Directory.Exists (path)) {
    // it's a directory, but we want a file
    return false;
  }

  var scriptPathInfo = new ScriptPathInfo (scriptAsset);

  //        Debug.Log (scriptPathInfo.scriptPath);
  //        Debug.Log (Path.GetFullPath(AssetsPath + "/../"));
  //        Debug.Log (scriptPathInfo.editorRelativeAssetPath);
  //        Debug.Log (scriptPathInfo.editorPath);

  if (File.Exists (scriptPathInfo.editorPath)) {
    // editor has already been created
    return false;
  }

  // all good!
  return true;
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful. I would be glad if you could take a look at this Unity Editor question for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52790971/scene-view-cannot-recognise-movement-of-several-objects-in-the-editor-until-obje/52791435?noredirect=1#52791435