# Scene view cannot recognise movement of several objects in the editor until objects are selected

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I created a game object and added a `SpriteStuff` script to it that I created with a various properties and functions for the game object. I also made a few copies of the object.
After, I made a `GroupSpriteStuff` game object which has the following property

```
public List<SpriteStuff> spriteStuffs;
```

I added an editor script for `GroupSpriteStuff` (`GroupSpriteStuffEditor`) that iterates through `spriteStuffs` to move each object using a slider.
The movement of objects in `spriteStuffs` is only seen when I select the  objects after moving the slider, if I don't select the objects after moving the slider the changes are aren't visible in the scene view. Below is the `GroupSpriteStuffEditor`:

```
GroupSpriteStuff groupSpriteStuff;    
float groupSpritesMvmtSliderValue = 0.0f;

void OnEnable()
{
    groupSpriteStuff = (GroupSpriteStuff)target;
}

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    base.OnInspectorGUI();

    EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();

    groupSpritesMvmtSliderValue = EditorGUILayout.Slider("Group Movement", groupSpriteStuff.originalGroupSpritesMvmtSliderValue, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    if (!Mathf.Approximately(groupSpriteStuff.originalGroupSpritesMvmtSliderValue, groupSpritesMvmtSliderValue))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < groupSpriteStuff.spriteStuffs.Count; i++)
        {
            spriteStuffs[i].UseTestMovement(0.2f);
        }

        groupSpriteStuff.originalGroupSpritesMvmtSliderValue = groupSpritesMvmtSliderValue;
    }

    if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
    {

        SceneView.RepaintAll();
    }

}
```

How can I get the scene view to update/recognise the changes in movement I make with the slider?

Comment: This code does not actually move anything at all... I am guessing, the movement is in some of the object's components' `Update` method? Just make sure that aside from changing the value of the variable, this call actually moves the object or triggers an `Update` (or whatever you use to make your object move). `Repaint` probably does not actually call `Update` on all objects...?

Comment: @Domi `UseTestMovement` moves objects and it works. I don't move the objects using the `Update` method. Also the movement is not seen in the scene view when I move the slider until the objects are selected, that alone is evidence that it's actually working, but the scene view is not updating the movement properly

Answer (score 0):

`OnInspectorGUI` is only called while moving in the Object's Inspector.

Instead you can use [`OnSceneGUI`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.OnSceneGUI.html) whis is repeately called while moving in the Scene View instead.

You have to separate the Inspector from the SceneView code.

`OnEnable` in an Editor is called when the Inspector is loaded due to selecting the object. Instead initialize your inspector with `Awake`:

```c#
GroupSpriteStuff groupSpriteStuff;    
float groupSpritesMvmtSliderValue = 0.0f;

void Awake()
{
    groupSpriteStuff = (GroupSpriteStuff)target;
}

private void OnSceneGUI()
{
    // to be sure you could also add it here
    groupSpriteStuff = (GroupSpriteStuff)target;

    groupSpritesMvmtSliderValue = EditorGUILayout.Slider("Group Movement", groupSpriteStuff.originalGroupSpritesMvmtSliderValue, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}

private void OnSceneView()
{
    groupSpriteStuff = (GroupSpriteStuff)target;

    if (!Mathf.Approximately(groupSpriteStuff.originalGroupSpritesMvmtSliderValue, groupSpritesMvmtSliderValue))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < groupSpriteStuff.spriteStuffs.Count; i++)
        {
            //you were also missing groupSpriteStuff again here
            groupSpriteStuff.spriteStuffs[i].UseTestMovement(0.2f);
        }

        groupSpriteStuff.originalGroupSpritesMvmtSliderValue = groupSpritesMvmtSliderValue;
    }
}
```

Though be careful: you are setting the float value everytime to 0 again. That might lead to problems as well.

Comment: I used the code you provided but the slider didn't appear in the inspector window

Comment: See my update: I think you have to separate the Inspector and the SceneView -> in the Inspector draw the slider and adjust the value, in the SceneView do the rest.

Comment: I removed the initial value 0 for `groupSpritesMvmtSliderValue`. The slider still wasn't appearing so I went back to `OnInspectorGUI` for the definition of the slider and placed the rest in `OnSceneGUI` but the slider wasn't moving from zero. Segmenting the slider definition and it's updating doesn't seem to be working, that is according to the code you provided.